# How can I hide my menu of buttons while printing?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, printing, hide

I have a button that prints the current page being viewed.  I want to hide my menu of buttons which is contained inside of the div 'mainMenuDiv', when I go to print.

None of the following seems to work and produces an error of uncaught style of null.

```
document.getElementById('mainMenuDiv').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('mainMenuDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Here is my print screen code

```
    <button className="printBtn" onClick={this.printPage}>PRINT SCREEN</button>

printPage() {
        window.print();
    }
```

Not sure how I can hide mainMenuDiv without using the above document.getElementById calls

Comment: what `console.log(document.getElementById('mainMenuDiv'))` prints in your dev tools?

Comment: null / undefined

Comment: So you have your answer ;) Element is not found in your HTML. Double check if ID in your javascript code matches actual ID in the HTML and if your script is added just before the `body` closing tag.

Comment: I should probably take into consideration that mainMenuDiv is a CLASS not an ID  -  ugh oops

Comment: now it gives me 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined'

Comment: did you check if it matches any html element after that change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) type called `print` and control it via CSS:

```
@media print {
  #mainMenuDiv {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: [Yes](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_media__media), just as regular CSS.